Two-Sample Mendelian Randomization: Association between Instrumental Variable and Outcome
Can someone tell me when selecting the instrumental variables for Two-sample MR analysis, why we don't care the association between Instrumental Variable and Outcome variable? If G is a valid instrumental variable, doesn't it apply that the effect of G on the outcome Y is fully mediated by the exposure variable X?
My understanding is that when we perform the MR, we don't know that whether X is causally associated with Y, or their association is just because the confounding variable. And if we select the instrumental variable not only strongly associated with exposure but also associated with the outcome, it is actually leading the selection bias, am I right?
